# param_grid error when using Xgboost for tuning

Tags: python, machine-learning, hyperparameters

I am trying to write code for hyperparameter tuning on the XG Boost model. However, I keep getting an error. Here is the code:

```
#define X,y
y = data.SalePrice
x = data.drop(['SalePrice'], axis=1).select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])

#test,train split
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

#Imputation transformer for completing missing values.
my_imputer = Imputer()

#Seperate train and test X
train_x = my_imputer.fit_transform(train_x)
test_x = my_imputer.transform(test_x)
```

Then, here is the hyperparameter for the data:

```
# Set the parameters by cross-validation
tuned_parameters = [{'n_estimators': [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500],'learning_rate': [0.01,0.05]}]
scores = ['precision', 'recall']

for score in scores:
    print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for %s" % score)
    print()

    #XGBRegressor
    clf = GridSearchCV(XGBRegressor(tuned_parameters), cv=5,scoring='%s_macro' % score)
    clf.fit(train_x, train_y)

    print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
    print(clf.best_params_)
```

The error I am getting is :TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param_grid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you misplaced your `tuned_parameters` :D; try redoing the `clf` definition as

```
clf = GridSearchCV(XGBRegressor(), param_grid=tuned_parameters, cv=5,scoring='%s_macro' % score)
```

and let me know if that works.